Combinations of Groups of People and the Probability of People being in the Same Group?
Question: Ms. Vena has 25 students in her class. For the next lesson, she would like to put the students into groups of 5. What is the probability that Samantha and Daniel are in the same group?
Answer: 1/30
Method: (23C3) assuming that Samantha and Daniel are in the same group, there are 23 people left to fill the remaining 3 spots in the first group. We then divide this by (25C5) which represents the total number of ways 5 people can be selected from a class of 25.
My confusion: For a previous question:"Ms. Vena has 25 students in her class. In how many different ways can the students be put into groups consisting of 5 students in each group?" We have to do (25C5)(20C5)(15C5)(10C5)(5C5) to find the total ways the 5 groups of 5 can be composed. So for the probability of the first question, why do we assume that Samantha and Daniel are going to be picked in the first group when all 25 students are not grouped yet, hence why we do 23C3/25C5. Why do we not assume they are picked in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th selection if the only condition is they have to be together.
Also, shouldn't n(S) in the first question be: (25C5)(20C5)(15C5)(10C5)(5C5) as this is the total number of ways the students can be put into 5 groups of 5. If the question was only asking how many ways can a single group of 5 be selected from a group of 25, then it would make more sense here to have n(S) = only 25C5?
This question must be solved using combinations, not permutations so isn't assuming they are in the first group give order a purpose and therefore change the question into a permutation. Any help is greatly appreciated because I've been stuck on this one for so long!!!

Your doubt is genuine, the book answer is incorrect.
As you have observed, Samantha and Daniel could be together in any of the five groups, so the correct answer should be five times the book answer, i.e.  $Pr= \Large\frac16$
And your observation regarding $n(S)$ is also correct, and since you say that only combinations are to be used, the full expression would be
$$Pr =5*\dfrac{\left[\binom22\binom{23}3\right]\binom{20}5\binom{15}5\binom{10}5\binom55}{\binom{25}5\binom{20}5\binom{15}5\binom{10}5\binom55}$$
but note that it simplifies to $$Pr= 5*\dfrac{\binom{23}3}{\binom{25}5} = \dfrac16$$
so the cancelling out terms can be omitted at the start without harm.

However, since probability has been asked for, we can get the answer mich more simply  without counting if we look at it as $5$ groups of $5$ slots, and just place Samantha and Daniel appropriately in slots.
$\square\square\square\square\square\;\;\square\square\square\square\square\;\;\square\square\square\square\square\;\;\square\square\square\square\square\;\;\square\square\square\square\square\;\;$
Samanatha can be placed in any slot,
and Daniel must occupy one of the $4$ slots left in that group,
thus P(Daniel is in the same group) $= \Large\frac4{24} = \frac16$


If any of the answers  are acceptable to you, you should tick an answer so that the question is closed

My old friend @trueblueanil gave you super easy way, so I will give you the long one that contain permutation calculation.
For the denominator, the number of ways to place $25$ students into $5$ groups without restriction is : $$\frac{\binom{25}{5}\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}}{5!}$$
We divide by $5!$ to convert these $5$ different teams into groups,i.e, indistinguisable teams. You made mistake in dividing by $5!$. Think that how many ways there are separating $5$ people into $5$ groups where there are only one person in each group. The answer is $1$, but if we dont divide by $5!$, the answer is $120$.
Now, we should select $3$ people for the team of Samantha and Daniel. So, the question turned out to be divide $23$ people into $5$ groups such that four of them have $5$ people and the rest has $3$ people:
$$\frac{\binom{23}{3}\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}}{4!}$$
The probability: $$\frac{ \frac{\binom{23}{3}\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}}{4!}}{\frac{\binom{25}{5}\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}}{5!}}=\frac{1}{6}$$
